# Kafka Streams - Consumer memory overload

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am planning a Spring+Kafka Streams application that handles incoming messages and stores updated internal state as a result of these messages.
This state is predicted to reach ~500mb per unique key (There are likely to be ~10k unique keys distributed across 2k partitions).

This state must generally be held in-memory for effective operation of my application but even on disk I would still face a similar problem (albeit just at a later date of scaling).

I am planning to deploy this application into a dynamically scaling environment such as AWS and will set a minimum number of instances, but I am wary of 2 situations:

- On first startup (where perhaps just 1 consumer starts first) it will not be able to handle taking assignment of all the partitions because the in memory state will overflow the instances available memory.
- After a major outtage (AWS availability zone outtage) it could be that 33% of consumers are taken out of the group and the additional memory load on the remaining instances could actually take out everyone who remains.

How do people protect their consumers from taking on more partitions than they can handle such that they do not overflow available memory/disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/).

Since 0.11...

[image]

**EDIT**

For your second use case (and it also works for the first), perhaps you could implement a custom `PartitionAssignor` that limits the number of partitions assigned to each instance.

<strike>I haven't tried it; I don't know how the broker will react to the presence of unassigned partitions.</strike>

**EDIT2**

This seems to work ok; but YMMV...

```
public class NoMoreThanFiveAssignor extends RoundRobinAssignor {

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<TopicPartition>> assign(Map<String, Integer> partitionsPerTopic,
            Map<String, Subscription> subscriptions) {

        Map<String, List<TopicPartition>> assignments = super.assign(partitionsPerTopic, subscriptions);
        assignments.forEach((memberId, assigned) -> {
            if (assigned.size() > 5) {
                System.out.println("Reducing assignments from " + assigned.size() + " to 5 for " + memberId);
                assignments.put(memberId, 
                        assigned.stream()
                            .limit(5)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            }
        });
        return assignments;
    }

}
```

and

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So54072362Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54072362Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so54072362", 15, (short) 1);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so54072362", topics = "so54072362")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        System.out.println(record);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                template.send("so54072362", i, "foo", "bar");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.partition.assignment.strategy=com.example.NoMoreThanFiveAssignor
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

and

```
Reducing assignments from 15 to 5 for consumer-2-f37221f8-70bb-421d-9faf-6591cc26a76a
2019-01-07 15:24:28.288  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Successfully joined group with generation 7
2019-01-07 15:24:28.289  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Setting newly assigned partitions [so54072362-0, so54072362-1, so54072362-2, so54072362-3, so54072362-4]
2019-01-07 15:24:28.296  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so54072362-0, so54072362-1, so54072362-2, so54072362-3, so54072362-4]
2019-01-07 15:24:46.303  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2019-01-07 15:24:46.303  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Revoking previously assigned partitions [so54072362-0, so54072362-1, so54072362-2, so54072362-3, so54072362-4]
2019-01-07 15:24:46.303  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [so54072362-0, so54072362-1, so54072362-2, so54072362-3, so54072362-4]
2019-01-07 15:24:46.304  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] (Re-)joining group
Reducing assignments from 8 to 5 for consumer-2-c9a6928a-520c-4646-9dd9-4da14636744b
Reducing assignments from 7 to 5 for consumer-2-f37221f8-70bb-421d-9faf-6591cc26a76a
2019-01-07 15:24:46.310  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Successfully joined group with generation 8
2019-01-07 15:24:46.311  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Setting newly assigned partitions [so54072362-9, so54072362-5, so54072362-7, so54072362-1, so54072362-3]
2019-01-07 15:24:46.315  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so54072362-9, so54072362-5, so54072362-7, so54072362-1, so54072362-3]
2019-01-07 15:24:58.324  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2019-01-07 15:24:58.324  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Revoking previously assigned partitions [so54072362-9, so54072362-5, so54072362-7, so54072362-1, so54072362-3]
2019-01-07 15:24:58.324  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [so54072362-9, so54072362-5, so54072362-7, so54072362-1, so54072362-3]
2019-01-07 15:24:58.324  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] (Re-)joining group
2019-01-07 15:24:58.330  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Successfully joined group with generation 9
2019-01-07 15:24:58.332  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=so54072362] Setting newly assigned partitions [so54072362-14, so54072362-11, so54072362-5, so54072362-8, so54072362-2]
2019-01-07 15:24:58.336  INFO 23485 --- [o54072362-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so54072362-14, so54072362-11, so54072362-5, so54072362-8, so54072362-2]
```

Of course, this leaves the unassigned partitions dangling, but it sounds like that's what you want, until the region comes back online.

Comment: Thanks kindly for the answer Gary. This would be a belt and braces fix approach requiring us to put some effort into capacity planning for the future but it's not impossible to do and I like the simplicity.

Another similar scenario I have recently become aware of is one of 'mass failure' e.g. the same situation occurs if an AWS availability zone would be to fail and take out 1/3 of your consumers. Do you have any thoughts as to what to do in that situation too?

Comment: I have revised the initial question to make clear the 2 situations in which 'memory protection' might be needed. I'll mark yours as accepted answer if no-one suggests anything reasonable for scenario 2 in a decent frame of time :)

Comment: The only thought that comes to my mind would be to manually assign partitions rather than using group management; but that pretty much eliminates dynamic scaling (and I am not even sure if it's even possible with streams).

Comment: I  had another idea; I don't know how practical it is, but it seems to work; see the edits to my answer.

Comment: Your assignor suggestion sounds plausible - albeit this is a Kafka Streams application and Spring has already implemented an Assignor (That presumably handles the logic of making sure you assign the same partitions across multiple topics, stores etc) and whenever i've tried to change this I run into some pretty painful issues.

Have you had any experience overriding the assignor in a kafka streams spring app?

Comment: To elaborate - in org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig partition.assignment.strategy is hardcoded to StreamsPartitionAssignor.class.getName() in the getMainConsumerConfigs method.

I tried to extend StreamsConfig and replace with a simple assignor that just printed the assignments as they happen but ran into a whole host of peculiar errors as it seems they really don't want you messing with that Assignor!

Comment: Yes, sorry; I haven't played with Streams much; I was looking at it from a pure Kafka perspective; I guess you are out of luck then.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your help. I'll accept your answer as the most relevant for now as it does give me some ideas if only I could mess with that Assignor logic! (At least I can raise a more specific Streams Q about how to modify Assignor now)